# Style: a tuple is returned

Tags: python

I have come across such a coding style for cases when a tuple is returned.

```
_, number_of_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
```

In this case `monthrange` returns a tuple with two values:  weekday of first day of the month and number of days in month.

1. Is this style acceptable? Is it described in some famous style guides like Google Python Style Guide?
2. What should I do if `_` is already occupied? For example, in Django it is used for translation like this:

   ```
   from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
   output = _("Welcome to my site.")
   ```

Comment: The `_` is commonly used to store return values you don't intend to use - it's just a convention, so you can replace it with any other valid identifier

Comment: That being said, importing a function `as _` seems bad style IMO - it makes the usage of that function unclear and obscure

Comment: What kind of genius came up with the idea to name `gettext` `_` anyway?

Comment: It's a pretty common pattern, even mentioned in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext

Comment: @Rawing, this is in the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/ Anyway this is already a well established practice in Django. So, what could you suggest to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the single underscore "\_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: I'm aware it's a common pattern, I'm just wondering _why_.

Comment: Usually `_` is seen as a throwaway variable. For instance a python interactive shell uses `_` to store the *last* result. The fact that some libraries use `_` is actually a bad practice.

Comment: @Rawing it comes from C; it is a name without use in C, and `_` is less to type than `gettext`; [gettext documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Mark-Keywords.html#Mark-Keywords). Note that there is no official use for `_` in Python either, just some conventions and a special behaviour in the REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, we sould follow the advice from The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python:

http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/style/#create-an-ignored-variable

That is: use __ in this case.